# Find n Nearest Neighbors for given Point using PostGIS?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I am trying to solve the problem of finding the n nearest neighbors using PostGIS:

Starting Point:

- Table geoname with geonames (from
  geonames.org) containing
  latitude/longitude (WSG-84)
- Added a GeometryColumn geom with
  srid=4326 and datatype=POINT
- Filled geom with values: UPDATE geoname
  SET geom =
  ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(longitude,latitude),
  4326);
- Created GIST index for geom (CREATE
  INDEX geom_index ON geoname USING GIST (geom);) / Clustered geom_index: CLUSTER geom_index ON
  geoname;)
- Created PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE BTREE index for geonameid

Problem:
Find n (e.g. 5) nearest neighbors for a given Point in table geoname represented by id (geoname.geonameid.

Possible solution:

Inspired by http://www.bostongis.com/PrinterFriendly.aspx?content_name=postgis_nearest_neighbor, I tried the following query:

```
"SELECT start.asciiname, ende.asciiname, distance_sphere(start.geom, ende.geom) as distance " +
"FROM geoname As start, geoname As ende WHERE start.geonameid = 2950159 AND start.geonameid <> ende.geonameid " +
"AND ST_DWithin(start.geom, ende.geom, 300) order by distance limit 5"
```

Processing time: about 60s

Also tried an approach based on EXPAND:

```
"SELECT start.asciiname, ende.asciiname, distance_sphere(start.geom, ende.geom) as distance " +
"FROM geoname As start, geoname As ende WHERE start.geonameid = 2950159 AND start.geonameid <> ende.geonameid AND expand(start.geom, 300) && ende.geom " +
"order by distance limit 5"
```

Processing time: about 120s

The intended application is some kind of autocomplete. So, any approach taking longer than >1s is not applicable. Is it generally possible to achieve a response time of <1s with PostGIS?

Comment: I think you have a better chance at http://gis.stackexchange.com/ to get an answer.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Now since PostGIS 2.0, there's a KNN index for geometry types available.
This gives you nearest 5 records with regard to how far they are away from "your location...".

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table 
ORDER BY your_table.geom <-> "your location..."
LIMIT 5;
```

See `<->` operator [in PostgreSQL manual](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-2.0/geometry_distance_centroid.html).

Comment: Neat! One of the many goodies coming with 2.0 release. I presume that will give you results faster? Do you know what (approximately) kind of speed up can you expect?

Comment: Just to clarify, the KNN index is actually implemented in PG >9.1, so make sure you have the proper version of PG installed... it's definitely worth checking it out...

Comment: Also marked this as the answer because it's probably the most efficient way of doing a nearest neighbor search using common db technology...

Comment: i tried this, but i get this error: operator does not exist: geography <->

Comment: @jipipayo Make sure u have PostGIS version >2.0.0 properly installed

Comment: @Paulo Casaretto i assume by "geographic points" you mean objects described by longitude/latitude, yes that's possible!

Comment: How it can be implemented for geographic(lat/lng)? I use SRID 4326, and get approximately results(((

Comment: This appears to work with geography when casting it to geometry: `your_table.geography_field::geometry <-> another_table.geography_field::geometry`

Comment: Hello, is the calculation when casting to geometry accurate from your experience?
Thanks a lot

Comment: I was ordering by distance before finding about this solution. My request performances went from 200ms to 1.5ms.

Answer (score 7):

As I think you were answered at the list the unit is in degrees so you area almost searching the whole world with 300 degrees in st_dwithin.

If your dataset is that big so you can't work in a projected meterbased projection instead (much faster and less cpu-intensive calculations) you should consider using the geograpphy type instead. Then you can use st_dwithin with meter.

The make things faster you should I would just create a new table with the geometry converted to geography.

But to just test it you can cast on the fly:

```
SELECT start.asciiname, ende.asciiname, 
ST_Distance(start.geom::geography, ende.geom::geography) as distance 
FROM geoname As start, geoname As ende 
WHERE start.geonameid = 2950159 AND start.geonameid <> ende.geonameid AND
ST_DWithin(start.geom::geography, ende.geom::geography, 300) 
order by distance 
limit 5;
```

HTH
Nicklas