# Query nearone points to a route

Tags: sql

I have the following table: `Position(x, y, t, userid)`

Is it any more effective implementation / data structure to retrieve positions which are close to the position of a specific user walked over a day than the naive implementation I imagined?

This is my pseudo code:

```
loop all the t (time)
    query x0, y0 position of specific user in t
    query all x, y position close to x0, y0
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I have not jet decided, maybe mongodb, maybe sqlite

Comment: For GIS stuff Postgres + PostGIS is usually the best choice.

Comment: Or another dbms with native gis support...

Comment: now I see I have tree option: MongoDB 2.4, MySQL 5.5, PostgreSQL 9.2, but u said `PostgreSQL` support GIS stuff

Comment: If you go for Postgres use the current version 9.2 is pretty outdated. And PostGIS is apparently one of the best GIS options for relational databases. I think there is a reason that OpenStreetmap uses it

Comment: See, e.g. here https://boundlessgeo.com/2011/09/indexed-nearest-neighbour-search-in-postgis/ or here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/91765/improve-speed-of-postgis-nearest-neighbor-query or here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5111843/330315 for example queries